# How to make my folder in localhost as a executable file?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I have a folder in the localhost (local server folder) and what I want is to make it as an executable file where if you click that executable file, it will directly open to the web browser and also have its database.

Comment: Wait! What do you mean by executable? The files having .html extension will open in the browser.

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar Yes, this folder has a .php file extensions.

Comment: What do you mean by executable folder? Do you mean `localhost/foldername` will open a webpage? If then, add `index.php` or `index.html` to make it default webpage

Comment: What I mean is that, I'm going to make my folder as an executable file.

Comment: a folder is not a file. It's a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do deep research and it is possible to compile all your project from your locahost to the executable file.

I used:

- PHP Desktop Chrome by Czarek Tomczak
- DB Browser for SQLite (for my database connection)
- Inno Setup Compiler (to compile my project folder and convert it into executable file).

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a folder an executable file. But if I understand your concern correctly. You can follow this step.

1. Open your page in a browser (e.i Chrome)
2. Click the **Option Button** on right upper corner of the browser (the 3 vertical dot icon -*atleast in my case.*).
3. On **More Tools** Click **Add to Desktop**
4. Then provide what name you like.

And you're done. You can copy the shortcut and put it anywhere you want. You can also pin it to task bar.