# how to make shortcut of my localhost project on desktop

Tags: google-chrome

I have a web app project which I want to have a shortcut on my desktop so that I will only open it to access my project on a browser. How to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678125/how-to-make-my-folder-in-localhost-as-a-executable-file/48679356#48679356)

But FYR, I answer you with the same answer I gave to it.

1. Open your page in a browser (e.i Chrome)
2. Click the **Option** Button on right upper corner of the browser (the 3 vertical dot icon -atleast in my case.).
3. On **More Tools** Click Add to Desktop
4. Then provide what name you like.

Comment: For people who are watching this question as of 1/9/2021 the `Add to desktop` will be `create shortcut`